# Problema comr radiobutton asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boa noite ,estou tentando popular varis radiobutton conforme o valor contido no meu banco de dados ,porem não estou conseguindo fazer.

Aqui esta a view com o radiobutton

```
@model GuialetoLMS.Models.GuialetoModel
@foreach (var choice in Model.Vestibular)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("answer", @choice.idVestibular ) @choice.NomeVestibular
}
```

E meu controller

```
  public ActionResult PaginaQuestao()
    {
        return View(db.Vestibular.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Qual é o erro, o que está acontecendo?

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GuialetoLMS.Models.Vestibular]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'GuialetoLMS.Models.GuialetoModel'.

Comment: O tipo que você está passando para a view está errado `db.Vestibular.ToList()` está retornando um `GuialetoLMS.Models.Vestib‌​ular` e não um `@model GuialetoLMS.Models.GuialetoModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente a sua view está esperando um uma ViewModel `GuialetoLMS.Models.GuialetoModel` e você está passando uma para ela um tipo diferente,`GuialetoLMS.Models.Vestib‌​ular`.

Se você desejava passar apenas a lista de Vestibular, basta alterar a declaração em sua view:

```
@model GuialetoLMS.Models.Vestib‌​ular
@foreach (var choice in Model)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("answer", @choice.idVestibular ) @choice.NomeVestibular
}
```

Mesmo você tendo incluído apenas um pequeno trecho do seu código deduzo que a primeira solução não irá resolver o seu problema, pois você deve desejar passar outros dados que estão contidos na `GuialetoModel`, então você deve criar uma instância desse objeto e popular com o conteúdo desejado.

```
public ActionResult PaginaQuestao()
{
    var viewModel = new GuialetoLMS.Models.GuialetoModel();

    //... resto do seu código

    viewModel.Vestibular = db.Vestibular.ToList();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: @RobsonOliveira Resolveu?